# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'string'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

With the latest version of Xcode from Apple, I have the following problem.

Upon launching, and starting a new project, no matter what the project, I get an error.

Let's say I would like to build a "Mac OS X Command Line Tool" of type "Foundation".

Then, to add a new class, I go to File > Add File > Cocoa Class > Objective-C Class (subclass of NSObject).

Next, in the .h file of the new class created, I replace with the following code:

```
//
//  newclass.h
//  Untitled
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface newclass : NSObject
{
    string userName;
}

@property string userName;

@end
```

And then the implementation with the following code:

```
//
//  newclass.m
//  Untitled
//

#import "newclass.h"


@implementation newclass

@synthesize userName;

@end
```

And then click "Build & Run" the following errors occur:

`newclass.h:11: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'string'`

`newclass.h:14: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'string'`

`newclass.m:11: error: no declaration of property 'userName' found in the interface`

What am i doing wrong?  I've looked up similar previous questions and they have all had to do with the fact that there have been missing or incorrect inputs as far as I can tell.

I can't seem to find out how mine would relate considering everything is from a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `NSString *`.  `string` is a C++ class and Objective-C is not C++.

Comment: I think I messed up on the most basic level.  What exactly is the syntax for ivars?  Thank you for the post btw.

Answer (score 1):

The `string` type hasn't been defined.  I think you meant to use `NSString *`

Answer (score 1):

Try change your .h like this

```
@interface newclass : NSObject
{
    NSString *userName;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userName;
```

why your implementation looks like your .h ..... ?

Comment: So sorry about the duplicate! :)

But, like I asked Carl, what exactly is the syntax for defining instance vars?

Comment: included an example of how to define an ivar.  For more detailed information you should read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html